# Is the use of neither-nor grammatically correct in this sentence?

Tags: neither-nor

Is the neither/nor structure used correctly in the following sentence?

> This treatment can’t be used if the root is too curved or it has got a tiny root canal that would not provide the needed space for the post. **Neither** when the fracture extends below the gum line **nor** for a tooth that has multiple canals.

I am asking this because I have learnt how we can use neither/nor before nouns or adjectives 
eg. “Neither Tom nor Jenny came to the party”
 or “this place is neither nice nor safe” but I'm not sure if I can use the structure together with 2 clauses?

Answer (score 1):

The second part isn't a sentence. You need to say something similar to,

> Neither can it be used when the fracture extends below the gum line
>   nor for a tooth that has multiple canals.